# Why is my webcam not detected on my Dell E6400?

Tags: dell, webcam

My webcam is not detected on my Dell E6400 laptop. Neither Skype, nor Cheese, nor Camora detects it. It is turned on in the CMOS, but `lsusb` doesn't see it.

Comment: is it detected on other operating systems?

Answer (score 0):

If it is not being detected by `lsusb`, i suspect it's a hardware issue. I might be wrong, but your webcam might just have become a vegetable.

Another possible issue can be if it's been accidentally switched off via the hardware buttons, if your laptop has a provision for it.

Comment: no hardware buttons available, so I guess it's just toast.

Comment: probably, is it detected on other operating systems?